# How to interpret Forecasting Models in R

Tags: r, graph, model, forecasting

I created a forecasting model using `stlf(), auto.arima(), HoltWinters()` methods in R and I get something like this:

[image]

What does the colouring mean i.e. what does the grey area and purplish area indicate?

Comment: Gray is 95% confidence intervals and purple is 80% confidence intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simple, it means that there is a 80 or 95 % chance that your future values will lie in the respectful shaded areas. On the other hand it also means that your point forecasts (dark blue line) have 0 % probability of realization.